# Paho-MQTT client disconnect with code 16 and cannot connect again

Tags: python, mqtt

I have this paho-mqtt python client (I have omitted some of the script logic and DB accessing for simplification):

```py
import json
import logging
import time

from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
mqtt_logger = logging.getLogger("MqttCon")


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt_logger.info("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("some_topic/#", qos=0)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    mqtt_logger.info("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))


def pub_values(client, base_topic, values):
    msg = json.dumps(values)
    target_topic = base_topic
    mqtt_logger.info("Sending message to wheel...")
    client.publish(target_topic, msg, qos=0)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    """
    Input messages format (can be one or list):
    {
        "tag_id": "string",
        "value": "int or float",
        "timestamp": "string format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.F"
    }
    """
    try:
        info = json.loads(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))
        mqtt_logger.info(msg.topic)
        pub_msg = {"tag_ids": [], "timestamp": ""}
        mqtt_logger.info(f"Received message topic is {msg.topic}")
        if isinstance(info, list):
            # some logic
        else:
            # some logic, writing values to InfluxDB
        pub_values(client=client, base_topic="some_topic", values=pub_msg)
    except Exception as e:
        mqtt_logger.error(str(e))


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    mqtt_logger.info(f"SYSTEM: {buf}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.on_log = on_log
    client.connect_async('<my_mqtt_url>', port=1883)

    client.loop_start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        mqtt_logger.warning("Stopping client")
        client.loop_stop()
        client.disconnect()
```

It works good for a few hours, but at some time it have disconnection:

```
INFO:MqttCon:Received message topic is telemetry/MESPIV/batch
INFO:MqttCon:Sending message to wheel...
INFO:MqttCon:SYSTEM: Sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m4228), 'b'router/newdata'', ... (11336 bytes)
INFO:MqttCon:Sending message to wheel...
INFO:MqttCon:SYSTEM: Sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m4229), 'b'router/newdata'', ... (11336 bytes)
INFO:MqttCon:Device disconnected with result code: 16
INFO:MqttCon:Device disconnected with result code: 16
INFO:MqttCon:SYSTEM: Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b''
INFO:MqttCon:SYSTEM: Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b''
# more Sending CONNECT
```

The client disconnects with code 16 (MQTT_ERR_KEEPALIVE), and tries to connect in an infinite loop, but it fails to connect (don't recive CONNACK). How can I solve this problem?
For mqtt docker container i use eclipse-mosquitto image.

My first code version worked by usial connect, but it has the same problem.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setting mqtt client
    client.connect('<my_mqtt_url>', port=1883)
    client.loop_forever()
    client.disconnect()
```

**Additions**:

1. If I restart the container with the mqtt client, it starts working, but after a few hours it disconnects again (with code 16) with the possibility of reconnecting.
2. I didn't suspend/resume the machine before the failures started - mqtt client and broker works on virtual machine.
3. I don't see any client connection attempts in the mqtt broker logs. But at the moment of client disconnecting it with code 16, I see that in broker logs the client broke the connection.
4. Did not launch wireshark
5. in the client logs there are disconnections with the code 16 with a successful reconnection, but it is impossible to reconnect from some kind.

**Kludge solution:**

- Becouse MQTT client works in Docker container, i modify on_disconnect in such way:

```py
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    mqtt_logger.info("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))
    if rc == 16:
        exit(1)
```

- Add restart: always to container.
  If there is dissconnect with code 16 -> application exits and container drops -> restarting container and it works for few hours.

At the time of restarting the container, there is a period of time during which data loss occurs from the mqtt broker.

Comment: Have you restarted the container, restarted the docker service? Did you suspend/resume the machine before the failures started? Do you see the connection attempts in the broker logs? Have you run something like wireshark to check the packets are getting routed as expected?

Comment: @hardillb answering on your questions:
1) If I restart the container with the mqtе client, it starts working, but after a few hours it disconnects again (with code 16) with the possibility of reconnecting.
2) I didn't suspend/resume the machine before the failures started - mqtt client and broker works on virtual machine
3) I don't see any client connection attempts in the mqtt broker logs. But at the moment of client disconnecting it with code 16, I see that in broker logs the client broke the connection.
4) Did not launch wireshark

Comment: Edits the question to add details

Comment: what is the frequency at which you are receiving the messages?

Comment: @NamanGupta
a) If i use sync connect - 160 messages at one moment with large period
b) if i use connect_async - one message per 15 seconds

Comment: @Motixa maybe you can try putting the messages in a queue in on_message and run a separate thread to process the messages in that queue.

Comment: @NamanGupta Thanks, but I'm more inclined to use connect_async